# Porque winsound.SND_ASYNC necessita de tempo para tocar?

Tags: python

Eu estou escrevendo um programa em python, que em determinado ponto ele toca um som.
Porém, ao tocar o som, eu gostaria que meu programa continuasse rodando, então usei o winsound.SND_ASYNC. No qual o meu código ficou assim:

```
winsound.PlaySound("Ring01.wav", winsound.SND_ASYNC)
```

O problema é que o programa roda tão rápido que ele acaba não tocando o som, achei isso estranho, fiz o debug e ele tocou. Com isso notei que este comando necessita de um tempo para tocar, até fiz uns testes colocando um sleep(1) e tocou por 1 segundo o som. Mas isso não faz sentido pra mim, pois ele deveria tocar normal enquanto meu programa roda, e meu programa não pode ter esse delay.

Já tentei usar o playsound, e esse trava o programa enquanto toca o som.

O que eu posso fazer para que o winsound.SND_ASYNC toque rapidamente antes do meu programa terminar?

Comment: Consegui resolver o problema com a linha de código:

winsound.PlaySound("Ring01.wav", winsound.SND_ALIAS | winsound.SND_ASYNC)